Selectively apply scene color management/transform
I want to render this scene/animation on a white background

It currently has the default AgX transforms

Because of this, if I composite my image onto a white background.
The white isn't actually white.

Is there someway I'm missing to use the colorspace node to do this?


You're basically on the right track. The way you have to do it is like this: in the Render Properties > Color Management set the View Transform to Raw and Look to None:

Then in the Compositor, plug the Render Layers > Image output into a Convert Colorspace node just like you did, but use the settings From: Linear Rec.709 and To: AgX Base sRGB.

By the way, if you want to put an image in the background instead of a plain color, when importing a JPG or PNG with an Image node the Color Space in the node is usually set to sRGB. Now you can do one of two things:

Use another Convert Colorspace node to convert the image, use the settings From: Linear Rec.709 and To: sRGB.


Or instead just switch the Color Space setting in the Image node to Linear Rec.709, the result will be the same. But when you change this setting, this color space will be used throughout Blender for this image, no matter if you are in the Image Editor or in the Shader Editor using it there in an Image Texture node. This setting will be applied everywhere, while the Convert Colorspace node works in the Compositor.




There it is. Thank you mr Brinkmann

@TheJeran You'Re welcome. I've added some additional information just for completion.
